# How do i get the nested hash within this hash

Tags: ruby, parsing, hash

I am having real difficulty referencing messages within this hash.

```
[
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 1,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 1,
    "Subject": "Test Message",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-17T00:00:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 1,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Test Message",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 2,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Test this Update",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 3,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "My New Message",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 4,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Reply",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:05:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 5,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Some sensible shit",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-17T17:23:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 14,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Message 2",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-21T14:10:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 16,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Message 2",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T16:22:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 25,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "Added via abacus\r\n",
        "FromCustomer": false,
        "UserID": 1,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T16:22:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 26,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "sdsdsdsd",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T16:40:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 27,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "test",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T17:02:00"
      },
      {
        "IBMessageID": 28,
        "MessageThreadID": 1,
        "MessageText": "test",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T17:06:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 5,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 1,
    "Subject": "Unit Test Thread",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-21T13:11:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 12,
        "MessageThreadID": 5,
        "MessageText": "Test Message",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-21T13:11:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 11,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 0,
    "Subject": "Test5",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-22T14:39:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 22,
        "MessageThreadID": 11,
        "MessageText": "Test5",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T14:39:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 13,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 0,
    "Subject": "Test6",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-22T14:41:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 24,
        "MessageThreadID": 13,
        "MessageText": "Test6",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T14:41:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 12,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 0,
    "Subject": "Test5",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-22T14:41:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 23,
        "MessageThreadID": 12,
        "MessageText": "Test5",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-22T14:41:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 14,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 1,
    "Subject": "Test",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-23T12:24:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 29,
        "MessageThreadID": 14,
        "MessageText": "Test",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-23T12:24:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 15,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 1,
    "Subject": "Accounts Test",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-23T15:35:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 30,
        "MessageThreadID": 15,
        "MessageText": "Accounts Test",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-23T15:35:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 16,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 2,
    "Subject": "Savings ",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-23T15:36:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 31,
        "MessageThreadID": 16,
        "MessageText": "Savings",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-23T15:36:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "MessageThreadID": 17,
    "CustomerID": 171,
    "MessageType": 2,
    "Subject": "Savings ",
    "OpenDate": "2015-09-23T15:37:00",
    "Closed": false,
    "ClosedDate": null,
    "Messages": [
      {
        "IBMessageID": 32,
        "MessageThreadID": 17,
        "MessageText": "Savings",
        "FromCustomer": true,
        "UserID": null,
        "Date": "2015-09-23T15:37:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My initial call is performed by the following code:

```
  def open_contact_messages(customer_id)

    customer_id = @customer.id
    response = get_call('/Messages/GetOpenedMessages/' + customer_id.to_s)
    response = JSON.parse(response.body)
    prettyresponse = JSON.pretty_generate(response)

    @openmessages = {}
    @openmessages = response.map do |openmessage|
      Contact.new(openmessage) 
    end

    return @openmessages
  end
```

The output shown above is from prettyresponse. In my initializer I have the following code. ibmessages is my attempt at referencing the data within messages but i get a cant convert string into integer error.

```
class Contact
  attr_accessor :message_customer_ID, :message_type, :message_subject, :message_text, :message_source, :message_thread_ID
  attr_reader :messages

  def initialize(options)

    @message_customer_ID        = options['CustomerID'].to_s 
    @message_type               = options['MessageType'].to_s 
    @message_subject            = options['Subject'].to_s 
    @message_source             = options['Closed'].to_s 
    @message_thread_ID          = options['MessageThreadID'].to_s 
    @messages                   = options['Messages']

  end

end
```

In my view I can output the entire hash but referencing the messages hash is proving difficult.

```
  - open_contact_messages(@customer.id).each do |openmessage|
    .message-container
      %p.message-intro
        Filler said....
      .message
        %h4.message-header.message-contents= "Message Subject : #{openmessage.message_subject}"
        %p.message-body.message-text= "Message Text : #{openmessage.message_text}"
        %p.message-body.message-source= "Message Source : #{openmessage.message_source}"
        %p.message-body.message-thread-ID= "Message Thread ID #{openmessage.message_thread_ID}"
        %p.message-body.message-thread-ID= "Message Test"
        %p.message-body.message-thread-ID
          - openmessage.messages do |message| 
            = message['MessageText']
```

I am getting a variety of errors based on the many approaches I have found online but no solution. The most common error is cannot convert integer to string.

Comment: When giving examples please pare them down to the mimimum needed to make the point.Your example is bloated beyond belief. Also, assign input values to variables (e.g., `my_hash = {...`) so readers can refer to those variables In answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reduce your sample input data into the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem you are seeing. Anything beyond that gets in the way of our helping you.

Comment: Apologies for that. Will do. Should i edit this one or is this just for future reference?

Comment: If no answers had been posted, I'd recommend deleting the question, editing, then undeleting. As there is an answer, however, you should not make any changes that would be inconsistent with the part of the data cited in the answer. You could still do a lot of paring, but I think it's probably best to leave it as is.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland Thanks. Will take that on board for next time. Think i was reprimanded for not having enough code once so went for overkill. Will try for the happy medium from now on.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an array of arrays, i.e. you have a bunch of message threads, each of them contains a bunch of messages.

With this code

```
@openmessages = response.map do |openmessage|
  Contact.new(openmessage) 
end
```

you create a `Contact` instance, and provide it a message thread, i.e. this part:

```
{
  "MessageThreadID": 1,
  "CustomerID": 171,
  "MessageType": 1,
  "Subject": "Test Message",
  "OpenDate": "2015-09-17T00:00:00",
  "Closed": false,
  "ClosedDate": null,
  "Messages": [ ... ]
}
```

In your constructor, you may directly assign from `options` hash only keys listed above, i.e.

```
@message_customer_ID        = options['CustomerID'].to_s   # ok
@message_type               = options['MessageType'].to_s  # ok
@message_subject            = options['Subject'].to_s      # ok
@message_text               = options['MessageText'].to_s  # not ok
@message_source             = options['Closed'].to_s       # ok
@message_thread_ID          = options['MessageThreadID'].to_s # ok
@messages                   = options['Messages'].to_s     # not ok
@ibmessages                 = options['Messages']['IBMessageID'].to_s # not ok
```

`Messages` key contains an array of messages, so you can't just convert them to string, but instead you need to store them as array, so you may process them further.

If you want to output an array of your messages, you need to change `@messages` assigning to an array, like this:

```
@messages = options['Messages']
```

Add a reader method to your `Contact` class:

```
class Contact
  attr_reader :messages
end
```

And after that you can use this reader in your view:

```
- openmessage.messages do |message|
  = message['MessageText']
```

Please, note to use `-` in front of `openmessage.messages do |message|` line, exactly as in my code above, and not `=`. The difference between them is that `=` writes the result to the buffer (i.e. outputs something), while `-` just runs some ruby code. In this context you don't want to write whole `openmessage.messages` array in your view in a serialized form, but instead to process it in a loop.

Comment: Thanks for stepping in to help. I have changed the post to reflect your changes you suggested but it is still coming back as [{"IBMessageID"=>1, "MessageThreadID"=>1, "MessageText"=>"Test Message", "FromCustomer"=>true, "UserID"=>nil, "Date"=>"2015-09-17T17:23:00"}, {"IBMessageID"=>2, "MessageThreadID"=>1, "MessageText"=>"Test this Update", "FromCustomer"=>false, "UserID"=>1, "Date"=>"2015-09-17T17:23:00"} etc etc etc 

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: I'm not getting an error with the code but rather the "-openmessage.messages do " code block in my view is returning the entire message array whereas I wish to be able to reference parts of it like MessageText as you were doing. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies again as i was playing with the code to see if something wasnt right. When i do that nothing is returned. Any suggestions? Is there any block of code you want me to show?

Comment: It should work now. Please, update your question with your current code now.

Comment: Just edited there but as the changes suggest. I havent changed much other than the changes suggested. Hopefully i'm wrong. Apologies that this is a bother. Hopefully i can get it resolved.